# Netbeans editor: Copying code from text, pdf

Tags: netbeans, copy, paste

I'm relatively new to Java - and Netbeans - and, like I have in the past, I like to copy and paste code to learn what the code will do. I have tried copying text from: a pdf, a word doc and a txt doc. Pasting the code into the editor fails. Is this standard for NetBeans?
I guess the obvious question is: is there a fix?
Thanks,
Happy day,
Shawn